# Remote event receiver setting LastModifiedBy to "SharePoint Program"

Tags: event-receivers, client-object-model, remote-event-receiver

I have a Remote Event Receiver, on a list, that fires every time an item is updated, and it works fine.

However the **Last modified by**-field on the item is set to **SharePoint program**. I have tried setting the field to a specific value, but it seems do do no good, it still ends up as **SharePoint Program** (I guess that Update() automatically set the last modified again)

```
private static void RemoveMemberGroupFromItem(ListItem item, Group memberGroup, User modifyingUser)
    {
        var userToken = modifyingUser.LoginName;

        // Some changes on the item

        item.FieldValues[ModifiedByField] = userToken;
        item.Update();
    }
```

I tried setting `properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties` to a specific value as well; (the `vti_modifiedby`) but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is because of `item.Update();` which sets the `ModifiedByField` to "SharePoint program". In server object model we would use `SystemUpdate()` to avert this. However, I am afraid there is no client object model equivalent of `SystemUpdate()`